# Unique symbol value on type level

Tags: purescript

Is it possible to have some kind of unique symbol value on the type level, that could be used to distinct (tag) some record without the need to supply a unique string value?

In JS there is Symbol often used for such things. But I would like to have it without using Effect, in pure context.

Well, it could even like accessing Full qualified module name (which is quite unique for the task), but  I'm not sure if this is a really relevant/possible thing in the Purescript context.

Example:

Say There is some module that exposes:

```
type Worker value state = 
  { tag :: String
  , work :: value -> state -> Effect state
  }


makeWorker :: forall value state. Worker value state


performWork :: forall value state. woker -> Worker value state -> value -> Unit
```

This module is used to manage the state of workers, it passes them value and current state value, and gets Effect with new state value, and puts in state map where keys are tags.

Users of the module:

In one module:

```
worker = makeWorker { tag: "WorkerOne", work }

-- Then this tagged `worker` is used to performWork:
-- performWork worker "Some value"
```

In another module we use worker with another tag:

```
worker = makeWorker { tag: "WorkerTwo", work }
```

So it would be nice if there would be no need to supply a unique string ("WorkerOne", "WorkerTwo") as a tag but use some "generated" unique value. But the task is that worker should be created on the top level of the module in pure context.

Comment: It's not at all clear what it is that you're asking. Perhaps if you could provide an example in JavaScript? Or maybe you could describe the ultimate result you're working towards?

Comment: Ok, I tried to compose the example case.

Comment: And then you're using those tags as identity? I.e. to tell if two workers are the same one?

Comment: Yes, this tag is used to lookup state value to pass to `worker.work` (passed to `performWork`). This is the identity of the worker state. And, actually, in a module, there is supposed to be only one tagged worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Semantics of PureScript as such is pure and pretty much incompatible with this sort of thing. Same expression always produces same result. The results can be represented differently at a lower level, but in the language semantics they're the same.

And this is a feature, not a bug. In my experience, more often than not, a requirement like yours is an indication of a flawed design somewhere upstream.

An exception to this rule is FFI: if you have to interact with the underlying platform, there is no choice but to play by that platform's rules. One example I can give is React, which uses the JavaScript's implicit object identity as a way to tell components apart.

So the bottom line is: I urge you to reconsider the requirement. Chances are, you don't *really* need it. And even if you do, manually specified strings might actually be better than automatically generated ones, because they may help you troubleshoot later.

But if you really insist on doing it this way, good news: you can cheat! :-)

You can generate your IDs effectfully and then wrap them in [`unsafePerformEffect`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-effect/2.0.1/docs/Effect.Unsafe#v:unsafePerformEffect) to make it look pure to the compiler. For example:

```hs
import Effect.Unsafe (unsafePerformEffect)
import Data.UUID (toString, genUUID)

workerTag :: String
workerTag = toString $ unsafePerformEffect genUUID
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming that is not possible with current means and without "dirty" tricks.